# Rails 4: simple wildcard search from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

What's the easiest way to do a quick wildcard search on a field from the console? I don't care against guarding against SQL injection.

I'm using **PostgreSQL**.

Searching for `title` with strings containing "emerging'

This works but is somewhat cumbersome. Curious if there was a shorthand?

```
Product.where("title @@ :q", q: "emerging")
```

Equally cumbersome but no longer appear to work for me in Rails 4:

```
Product.where("title ILIKE ?", "emerging")
Product.where("title ilike :q", q: "emerging")
```

I guess I'm looking for something like `Product.where(title: "*emerging*")`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should do it:

```
word = 'emerging'
Product.where('title ILIKE ?', "%#{word}%")
```

- The ILIKE makes the search not sensitive to the case (PostgreSQL feature!)
- the "%" wildcard makes the search match every product having a title containing "word" inside with (or without) stuff before and/or after.

Comment: I've been looking for a solution for this and all it took was adding an "i" on "like". Not even the active record documentation has ilike .... sheesh.

Comment: @nerdgasms the `like` or `ilike` functions are not related to `ActiveRecord` but to the DB system you are using.

Answer (score 4):

Use `LIKE`, like this:

```
Product.where('title LIKE ?', '%emerging%')
```